# How to match this SDE with Ito's formula

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I have a SDE of the following form

$\frac{dZ}{dt}=-\lambda Z+\sigma\alpha_t\beta$, where $\sigma$ being the standard deviation and $\alpha_t$ is the stochastic parameter. $\beta$ is deterministic. I have two main questions:

1. with $\alpha$ being stochastic, does it mean $Z$ also becomes stochastic because of the presence of $\alpha$?
2. I am trying to match this SDE with the standard one a.k.a $dX_t=\mu_tdt+\sigma_tdB_t$.

My attempt is as follows:

I can write my SDE as: $dZ=-\lambda Zdt+\sigma\alpha_t\beta dt$
We know that  $dt=dB_t^2$ through Ito's result. so I can rewrite the above as $dZ=-\lambda Zdt+\sigma\alpha_t\beta dB_t^2$

Can I say that I have achieved the general form now with: $\mu_t=-\lambda Z$ and $\sigma_t=\sigma\alpha_t\beta dB_t$?

Or I need to utilize the Ito's lemma here? Basically my final goal is to achieve a result for $E[Z]$.

Comment: No Ito's lemma can and needs to be used here. This "SDE" is an inhomogeneous linear ODE with a stochastic inhomogeneity. Fix your $\omega$ and use the standard ODE methods (variation of the constant).

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks. The parameter $\beta=\beta(t)$. Also, I didn't understand what you meant by fixing $\omega$? Did you mean write $dB^2_t=dt$ back and solve it in the usual way? I am not trying to solve it actually.

Comment: $\alpha_t(\omega)\,.$ Forget about Brownian motion. It has nothing to do with your "SDE". If you are not trying to solve this simple equation *why that question*?

Comment: oh okay. How to fix it? I have to find $E[Z]$. Thats why. Because we have the standard result $E[X_t]=\int\limits_0^t\mu_s ds$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

> $$Z_t=e^{-\lambda t}(Z_0+\sigma\beta\textstyle\int_0^te^{\lambda s}\alpha_s\,ds)\,,\quad E[Z_t]=e^{-\lambda t}(Z_0+\sigma\beta\textstyle\int_0^te^{\lambda s}E[\alpha_s]\,ds).$$

Comment: Thanks. Also, could you please tell how to compute $E[\alpha_s]$? Is it via the standard formula: $\int \alpha f(\alpha)d\alpha$? Also, whether $Z$ also is a stochastic variable/process now? As I asked in my question 1.  Thanks.

Comment: All you said about $\alpha_t$ that it is stochastic. How do you want me to calculate its expectation? It is a no brainer that $Z$ is stochastic now.

Comment: sorry newbie to stochasticity.